# Help with basic Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am teaching myself Linear Algebra and am trying to solve the following exercise from my book:

> Find the polynomial of degree 4 whose graph goes
>   through the points (1, 1), (2,−1), (3,−59), (−1, 5),
>   and (−2,−29).

Bretscher, Otto (2013-02-21). Linear Algebra with Applications (2-Download) (5th Edition) (Page 19). Pearson HE, Inc.. Kindle Edition.

Writing our polynomial:

$$
f(x) = ax + bx^2 + cx^3 + d^4
$$

Then, using the provided points to fill out a matrix:

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 4 & 8 & 16 & -1 \\
3 & 9 & 27 & 81 & -59 \\
-2 & 4 & -8 & 16 & -29
\end{array}
\right]
\space
$$

Rearrange the rows a little:

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 4 & 8 & 16 & -1 \\
-2 & 4 & -8 & 16 & -29 \\
3 & 9 & 27 & 81 & -59
\end{array}
\right]
\space
$$

Add Row 3 to Row 2, and Row 2 to Row 3:

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 8 & 0 & 32 & -30 \\
0 & 8 & 0 & 32 & -30 \\
3 & 9 & 27 & 81 & -59
\end{array}
\right]
\space
$$

Subtract Row 3 from Row 2, and Row 2 from Row 3:

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
3 & 9 & 27 & 81 & -59
\end{array}
\right]
\space
$$

Dropping rows two and three, because asserting zero equals zero helps us little:

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
3 & 9 & 27 & 81 & -59
\end{array}
\right]
\space
$$

Subtract three of Row 1 from Row 2:

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 6 & 24 & 78 & -62
\end{array}
\right]
\space
$$

Divide Row 2 by 6:

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 4 & 13 & -\frac{31}{3}
\end{array}
\right]
\space
$$

At this point, we have no pivots for c and d, so they would be set to so called "free variables" and we could express a and b in terms of c and d.

But my book, with no explanation, finds the following solution:

$$
f(t) = 1 − 5t + 4t^2 + 3t^3 − 2t^4
$$

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Your $f(x)$ is not a fourth degree polynomial.

Comment: You also have 5 points but only use four of them from what i can see.

Comment: Is... is there an operation in linear algebra for wiping the pie of my face?

Comment: "Add row 3 to row 2 and row 2 to row 3", these two operation cannot be performed simultaneously; I think this is where you went wrong.

Comment: While performing multiple ERO's at a time, you should keep notice of what you get after a single ERO so that the next ERO is justified.

Answer (score 1):

Your polynomial is not a fourth degree polynomial. Your initial setup should be

$$f(x) = a + bx + cx^2 + dx^3 + ex^4$$

Then, when you plug in $x=1,2,3,-1,-2$, you get $5$ equations for $5$ variables:

$$\begin{align}
a+b+c+d+e &= 1\\
a + 2b + 4c + 8d + 16e &=-1\\
a + 3b + 9c + 27 d + 81 e &= -59\\
a-b+c-d+e &= 5\\
a-2b+4c-8d+16e&=-29
\end{align}$$